# Maximize the determinant

Tags: matrices, analysis, optimization

Over the class $S$ of symmetric $n$ by $n$ matrices such that the diagonal entries are +1 and off diagonals are between $-1$ and $+1$ (inclusive/exclusive), is

$$\max_{A \in S} \det A = \det(I_n)$$
?

Comment: How did you determine that it equals $\det(I_n)$?

Comment: This is just a question, "Is ____  true?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Here is a randomly generated counterexample:
$$A=\frac18\pmatrix{
 8& 4&-4&-4& 5\\
 4& 8&-4&-7&-5\\
-4&-4& 8&-7& 4\\
-4&-7&-7& 8&-6\\
 5&-5& 4&-6& 8}.
$$
We have $\det(A)=\frac{2291}{2048}\approx1.1187$.

As a remark, if $A$ is not required to be symmetric and entries of $A$ are restricted to $\pm1$, $|\det(A)|$ can be extremely huge. It is known that $|\det(A)|\le n^{n/2}$ and this bound is sharp for some $n$ (and the maximisers are called *Hadamard matrices*), but no sharp upper bound is known to date for a general $n$. See [Hadamard's Maximum Determinant Problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HadamardsMaximumDeterminantProblem.html).

Comment: Good answer.  I suppose then what I really want to say then is.... will maximizing the determinant ever push an off diagonal to its bound?  I love this answer, so I don't want to rephrase my question again... but can I ask this as a second question.  I'm trying to get a handle on something.

Comment: @Squirtle If the maximum determinant is greater than $1$, some pair of off-diagonal entries must lie on the boundary. Consider $A+tS_{ij}$, where $i<j$ and $S_{ij}$ is the real symmetric matrix that has the value $1$ at the $(i,j)$-th and $(j,i)$-th entries and zero elsewhere. Then $\frac{d}{dt}(A+tS_{ij})=\det(A)\operatorname{trace}(A^{-1}S_{ij})$ (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Derivative)). By assumption, $A\ne I$. Hence $\operatorname{trace}(A^{-1}S_{ij})$ is nonzero for some $(i,j)$. In other words, $\frac{d}{dt}(A+tS_{ij})\ne0$.

Comment: Therefore, if all off-diagonal entries of $A$ do not lie on the boundary, we can choose a sufficiently small $t$ such that $\det(A+tS_{ij})>\det(A)$.

Answer (score 0):

For the three by three case I have the following. Let $A$ be generally defined as
$$A= \pmatrix{
 1& x& y\\
 x& 1&z\\
y&z& 1\\
}.
$$

Then the determinant is

$$|A| = 
\matrix{
1& z \\
z& 1 \\} - x\matrix{
x& z \\
y& 1 \\} + y\matrix{
x& 1 \\
y& z \\}
 = 1-z^2 - x(x-zy) + y(xz-y) =$$

$$= 1-x^2-y^2-z^2 +xyz-xyz= 1-(x^2+y^2+z^2)  \le 1 = \det(I_n)$$

Comment: I suppose this was the motivation of my question.  
As well as in the two by two case, clearly $\det([1, x ; x,1]) = 1-x^2 < 1$